# Passing styles in dangerouslySetInnerHtml in react overrides global css classes

Tags: reactjs

```
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
   .top-bar {
    background: green;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 TEST
</html>
```

When this is passed to dangerouslySetInnerHtml, the styles overrides global css of top-bar. Is there any safe mode for using dangerouslySetInnerHtml, so that its css remains only for the div which we set innerHtml ?

Comment: I'm guessing it's like adding inline css which overrides internal and external css styles added.

Comment: Is there a way to add 
localIdentName=[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5] 
to less-loader in webpack config ?

Answer (score 1):

Use a css class for your div:

```
<div className="my-div">...</div>
```

and then add your new class name to your html style:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .my-div.top-bar {
        background: green;
      }
    </style>
   </head>
   TEST
  </html>
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either add a class name as Fawas answered or use `!important` in global css